# C code to reverse a string using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    char* str;
    char* strrev;
    int   i = 0;
    int   j = 0;
    int   c;

    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);

    while (*(str + i) != '\n')
    {
        i++;
    }

    for (c = i; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        *(strrev + j) = *(str + c);
        j++;
    }
}
```

This is my code to reverse a string. When I compile the code , it gives an error `segmentation fault` . Someone plz help me understand the error and realize my mistake.
Thanks

Comment: Learn to format code, this helps preventing bugs.

Comment: Also learn to debug, that will help you finding the remaning bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *str,*strrev;
```

first your char buffers where never initialized.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/
second use strlen to determine string len

regards

Answer (score 5):

There are many issues:

- You never allocate memory for `str` or `strrev`. This is why it crashes; writing to uninitialized pointers invokes undefined behavior, often resulting in a seg fault.
- You're using `scanf()` with a complex conversion when you could just use `fgets()`.
- You should use `strlen()` rather than looping to find the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Following (some of) @unwinds pointers, here is some code that will reverse a string:
(you can use `scanf()`, but do not need such a complicated format string)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() 
{
   char str[260],strrev[260];
   int i=0, len;
   printf("Enter the string\n");
   scanf("%s",str);
   len = strlen(str);
    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {
        strrev[i-1] = str[len-i];   
    }
    strrev[len]=0;
    ;
}
```

If you would like to avoid using scanf, then replace it with something like:

```
char str[260], strrev[260];
//...
fgets(buf, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

***[EDIT-per comment]***  If still want to use a `char *`, do something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() 
{
   char *str, *strrev;
   int i=0, len;
   printf("Enter the string\n");
   str = malloc(260);
   strrev = malloc(260);
   scanf("%s",str);
   len = strlen(str);
    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {
        strrev[i-1] = str[len-i];   
    }
    strrev[len]=0;
    free(str);
    free(strrev);
}
```

Note:  Other than keystroke counting, I am not sure how you would determine at run-time just how many characters will be entered by a user.  So in this example, 260 bytes is assumed.

Comment: @ryyker- thanks ! but ,how can I do it using a character pointer ? and also I don't want to use in-built functions .

Comment: I assume you are saying you don't want to use _strlen()_, because you are already using a few built in functions (i.e. _scanf()_ and _printf()_).  However, if you really want to use char *, then memory allocation is required, and for that, _malloc()_ or _calloc()_ will be required at some point (more built in functions).  Are you allowed to set the maximum string length explicitly, or do you have to determine it at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @unwind, even if you used `str[100]`, the loop to find the length will fail.   Since `str` doens not have a `\n`, the `while()` loop never ends.

```
// bad
char str[100];
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
while (*(str + i) != '\n') {
  i++;
}

// better
char str[100];
scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", str);
while (*(str + i) != '\0') {  // look for \0
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    void mystrrev(char *);
    char str[100];
    char *p1;
    p1=str;
    printf("Enter the string..?\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    mystrrev(p1);
    printf("Reverse is =%s",p1);

}
void mystrrev(char *p1)
{

    char rev[100];
    char *r;
    r=rev;
    int i=-1,j=0;
    while(*p1!='\0')
    {
        p1++;
        i++;
    }
    while(i>=0)
    {
        p1--;
        *r=*p1;
        r++;
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    *p1='\0';
    *r='\0';
    while(j-1>=0)
    {
         r--;
         j--;
    }

    while(*r!='\0')
    {
        *p1=*r;
        p1++;
        r++;
    }
    *p1='\0';
}
```

**simple code**